# Attributing Points based on Direction

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, point

Using `QGIS 2.18.16` I am looking at "renaming" or changing the attributes of points to a unique attribute based on the direction of the points.

For example `A1, A2, A3`, then next row starts over as `B1, B2, B3`...

I would like to start at the furthermost point `SW` and gong in a straight line `NE` to the end until there is no longer points, then start again with the next row to the west.

Any help would be great.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you edit and attach an image showing a small section with the points actually labelled as you describe? Not totally sure what you're asking here. Also, could you share the final aim of this data? Looks like a sample grid or flight plan ...

Comment: this will be used for a field sampling plan and just need a easy way to name the points  for example see second image above

Comment: answer found here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148008/create-a-reference-number-id-based-on-x-coordinate-in-qgis